# How to use google image url as src for image

Tags: html, image

I am trying to use a photo that I have in Google Images in a website as the src.  I go to the image, and set he permissions to public.  I try the link and it works correctly just in the address bar of the browser.

But when I put it in a webpage, the browser blocks the access to it and says the issue is: Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB)

How do I resolve that?

Comment: I don't think there's anything you can do about it since it's controlled by the owner of the site (i.e. Google).  You'd have to copy the image into your own website.  More info: https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers/

Comment: I'm betting that the part of the error message you **didn't** quote is telling you that the URL points to an HTML document and not an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should download the image update it to your google drive and the make it public copy its link and try it out if it works or not